# Is there a Google CloudBuild equivalent for Manual Approval Action in AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am looking to setup a manual approval before the production build can be triggered from staging.

Is there any workaround to setup manual approval if Google doesn't support it natively?

AWS Manual Approval Action : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals-action-add.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no equivalent of AWS Manual Approval Action for Cloud Build, however, you can integrate Cloud Build with a 3rd party tool to implement a deployment approval for different enviroments. [Here is an article](https://medium.com/segmentstream/simple-ci-cd-on-gke-using-cloudbuild-and-spinnaker-8470c7832c6) that uses Spinnaker for that.

You could also open a Feature Request so that an implementation of a native approval for deployment can be considered by Google's Product Team by following this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190802&template=0).

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in preview for Cloud Build, but it needs to be enabled from the Early Access page at the org level.

[image]

Comment: It's not the same. What we're looking is for a manual approval on "Deploy to Prod" like every CI/CD product has

Comment: Your project should be the context of your environment. The cloud build trigger can either run inside your "prod" project. Or if you have an external CI/CD project you then simply create a "prod" trigger with manual approval. ?

Comment: Yes but then the build has to be done again? Ideally we would build once and move through stages, so we know that what was tested is what is being deployed

Comment: From cloud build you would push your tested code, package, or image to somewhere like Container Registry or Artifact Registry (e.g. myapp:v1.0.3). Now you know you just need to reference myapp:v1.0.3 as you roll it out to your different environments for testing. This can be done with cloud build again. You could then have a Prod cloud build trigger that requires approval before it can deploy the package. Cloud build isn't the best CI tool available but it can work.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Google Cloud product for just this purpose:
[Google Cloud Deploy](https://cloud.google.com/deploy)

Currently supports GKE and Anthos user clusters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no step-by-step manual approval like the aws code build or code pipeline, is that correct?

I couldn't find anything in the build configuration schema file either.

- Link : https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).